# ¿Como se puede establecer permisos sin conflictos entre usuarios y grupos?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permisos

Estoy teniendo problemas para encontrar un cierto equilibrio entre los permisos de propietarios y grupos de directorios y archivos.

Mientras avanza el desarrollo de la aplicación, aumentan los procesos que intervienen. Y cada uno de ellos se ejecutan con propietarios y grupos distintos.

El problema que me encuentro es el siguiente:

Pongo como ejemplo estos directorios.

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data cache/
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data log/
drwx------  2 www-data www-data sessions/
```

En ocasiones, el usuario `ubuntu` tiene que hacer alguna operación sobre los archivos que contienen estos directorios, *por ejemplo* `log/`. Con el consiguiente error lógico, por que no es propietario ni pertenece al grupo.

Como prueba, añadí el usuario `ubuntu` al grupo `www-data`.

Cuando es el usuario `ubuntu` quien crea antes el archivo `log`, se da el caso siguiente:

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 www-data www-data log/
├── -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data log.error.20170315.log
├── -rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data log.error.20170322.log
└── -rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu log.error.20170327.log
```

Crea el archivo `log` con el usuario y grupo `ubuntu`. En el caso de que el usuario `www-data` quiera editar ese mismo archivo vuelve a dar errores.

Mi pregunta entonces es:

¿Como se puede establecer permisos entre usuarios y grupos sin generar este tipo de conflictos?

Comment: ¿El planteamiento de incluir al usuario www-data en el grupo de ubuntu y al usuario ubuntu en el grupo de www-data sería una posibilidad?
¿O hay otros factores que impedirían una correcto funcionamiento con esta modificación?

Comment: @Eduardorq Es una posibilidad. Una de las razones por las que tampoco estoy seguro de si es una buena opción usar ese cruce de permisos es por tema seguridad, al ser `www-data` el usuario más expuesto, no quiero darle acceso a mas directorios de los que necesita.

Comment: Tienes razón @OscarR es mejor no cruzar en exceso los permisos. 
Tendrías que realizar la escritura con un mismo usuario o determinarle un grupo que puedan luego leer o modificar los usuarios que te interesen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, yo en casos parecidos al tuyo cuando quiero que varios usuarios pertenecientes a un grupo por ejemplo `www-data` puedan leer y escribir en un directorio y que al crear ficheros o directorios estos por defecto pertenezcan el grupo `www-data` lo que hago es activar el `SGID` del directorio, así.

```
chmod +s log
```

Con esto consigues que todos los ficheros o directorios creados dentro de `log` tengan asignado el grupo del directorio `log`.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Voy a investigar un poco sobre el tema y te comento.

Comment: Por ahora las pruebas que he realizado dan resultado positivo. Por verificar una cosa, añado el usuario `ubuntu` al grupo `www-data` y los permisos para esos directorios los edito: `dir 2775` `file 0664` `umask 002`, de forma que los usuarios del grupo también tendrían permisos de edición. ¿Sería correcto?

Comment: Exacto, con umask 002 los nuevos ficheros y directorios quedarían con los permisos: dir 2773, file 0662 con lo que el usuario y el grupo tienen permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución, los demás usuarios tendría permisos de escritura y ejecución, pero no podrían acceder al directorio si no me equivoco.

Comment: Magnifico por la verificación y por la ayuda!!, como nota, `umask` restaba octales `664 (666-002)` y `775 (777-002)` ;-) pero se ha entendido!!

Answer (score 2):

Yo pondría lista ACL.
En Ubuntu es posible poner listas ACL para personalizar los permisos, y dar a cada usuario o grupo un permiso concreto.

Para ver la lista, puedes usar el comando getfacl

```
getfacl quijote.txt     #vemos la lista ACL del fichero quijote.txt
getfacl Videos          #vemos la lista ACL del directorio Videos
```

Para poner listas ACL hacemos:

```
setfacl -m "u:alumno:x" recurso
```

donde:
setfacl     #el comando para poner lista ACL a un recurso ubuntu
-m          #para poner permisos
u           #u para usuario, g para grupo
alumno      #el usuario al que vamos a dar la lista ACL
x           # los permisos que le vamos a dar
recurso     # la carpeta o fichero que vamos a cambiar los permisos

Ejemplo 1:
`setfacl -m "u:pepe:7" quijote.txt`

## Damos al usuario pepe permiso de nivel 7 (lectura, escritura y ejecución) sobre el fichero quijote.txt

Ejemplo 2:

```
setfacl -m "g:alumnos:5" quijote.txt
```

#Damos al grupo alumnos permisos de nivel 5 (lectura y ejecución) sobre el fichero quijote.txt

Ejemplo 3:

```
setfacl -m "u:usuario1:0" Videos
```

Damos al usuario usuario1 permiso de nivel 0 (ningún permiso) sobre la carpeta Videos

Y luego miramos las listas con getfacl

```
getfacl quijote.txt
#file:quijote.txt
#owner: jfd
#group: jfd
user::rw-
user pere: rwx
group::r--
group alumnos::r-x
mask::rwx
other:r--
```

Si tienes alguna duda, sólo tienes que buscar información acerca del comando
`setfacl`  y las listas ACL en Linux.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Los permisos funcionan de forma jerárquica. En este caso, si quieres que el usuario `www-data` modifique el `log`, ¿Por qué no crearlo con ese usuario, si el usuario `ubuntu` está en el grupo `www-data`? Eso sería la solución más sencilla.

En caso de que no quieras, el archivo `log` puede tener propietario `ubuntu` y grupo propietario `www-data`, que es otra solución para que acceda el usuario `www-data`.